# Function doesn't return anything and doesn't run when imported

Tags: python, pandas, function, import, scope

This is killing me, I've spent handful of hours trying to debug this on my own with no luck. Basically, I have a function1.py that uses Pandas to pulls in some csv files, join them according to my specifications, and is supposed to 1) print the resulting DF 2) write the DF to excel. The function1.py is its own module and is coded like this:

```
def getMerged(csv_files, output_name):

   import pandas as pd


   list_of_expiry_dfs = []

   for csvfile in csv_files:
       names = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol']             # this can also go outside the fn
       df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep=';', names=names)
       df = df.set_index('date')
       list_of_expiry_dfs.append(df)

   x = 1

   composite = list_of_expiry_dfs[0]
   for each in list_of_expiry_dfs:
       composite = composite.join(each, lsuffix=x-1, rsuffix=x, how='outer')
       x = x + 1


   yaxis =[]
   for expiry in csv_files:
       open = 'open (' + expiry[:6] + ")"
       high = 'high (' + expiry[:6] + ")"
       low = 'low (' + expiry[:6] + ")"
       close = 'close (' + expiry[:6] + ")"
       vol = 'vol (' + expiry[:6] + ")"
       yaxis.append(open)
       yaxis.append(high)
       yaxis.append(low)
       yaxis.append(close)
       yaxis.append(vol)
   composite.columns = yaxis

   print(composite)
   composite.to_excel(output_name, header=True)
```

'''

At the bottom of the function.py, I can optionally choose to run this function, by provided some parameters as follows:

```
csv_files = [
'BZ1219.csv',
'BZ0120.csv',
'BZ0220.csv',
'BZ0320.csv',
'BZ0420.csv'
]

getMerged(csv_files, output_name='test.xlsx')
```

And it works just fine when run as the main executable.  But that's not what I want to do.  I've identified a slew of issues I need help with.

First, I'm totally unable to return "composite" outside of the function. I've all types of solutions including return statements, global variables, setting the function equal to a variable, and also setting attributes. No matter what I do, I simply cannot assess composite outside of the function.

What I really want to do is to be able to import function1.py from another file and run it as I please. Aka function1.py containing code block 1 only (no code block 2). That other.py looks like this:

```
csv_files = ['BZ1219.csv','BZ0120.csv','BZ0220.csv','BZ0320.csv','BZ0420.csv']
output_name = "test.xlsx"


from function1 import getMerged


getMerged(csv_files=csv_files, output_name=output_name)
```

This doesn't return an error, but also doesn't do anything.  The closest I've gotten is by adding the following code to code block 1.  It does.. well, something.  But it kicks the function into an infinite loop which eventually breaks down.

```
def getMerged(csv_files, output_name):
   ** insert the rest of first code block **
   output = getMerged(csv_files, output_name)
```

But it STILL doesn't give me the desired behavior when I import it.  I did make a number of other changes to other.py and at one point I was able to FINALLY to import function1.py successfully... but it was subject to the same issue, namely, running as an infinite loop due to the variable 'output' until it broken down.  I've changed the code so many times I dont even remember what that code change to other.py was

Please help!

Comment: Do not use `open` as variable name.

Comment: _all types of solutions including return statements ... setting the function equal to a variable_: Just to be sure, did you tried `return composite` at the very end of your function **and** assigning a variable equal to the function call (in that order, not the function equal to the variable)?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Good point regarding open.  And yes, no luck there.  setting the function equal to a variable is what kicks it into an infinite loops, regardless of what hacks I try to implement to stop it after a single run.  I partly wonder if it is not the Python code that is causing the issue, but rather somehow the Pandas join function, which required some tricks to use the way I want it to (aka the join + setting function = variable is what causes the infinite loop)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by setting composite as a global variable. Which will look something like this. Since it isn't working for you, I postulate that you haven't called the global variable in the function as such - `global composite`.

function1.py -

```
composite = []

def getMerged(csv_files, output_name):

   import pandas as pd

   global composite # I have a feeling you're missing this line.

   list_of_expiry_dfs = []

   for csvfile in csv_files:
       names = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol']             # this can also go outside the fn
       df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep=';', names=names)
       df = df.set_index('date')
       list_of_expiry_dfs.append(df)

   x = 1

   composite = list_of_expiry_dfs[0]
   for each in list_of_expiry_dfs:
       composite = composite.join(each, lsuffix=x-1, rsuffix=x, how='outer')
       x = x + 1


   yaxis =[]
   for expiry in csv_files:
       open = 'open (' + expiry[:6] + ")"
       high = 'high (' + expiry[:6] + ")"
       low = 'low (' + expiry[:6] + ")"
       close = 'close (' + expiry[:6] + ")"
       vol = 'vol (' + expiry[:6] + ")"
       yaxis.append(open)
       yaxis.append(high)
       yaxis.append(low)
       yaxis.append(close)
       yaxis.append(vol)
   composite.columns = yaxis

   print(composite)
   composite.to_excel(output_name, header=True)
```

In your other py file, -

```
csv_files = ['BZ1219.csv','BZ0120.csv','BZ0220.csv','BZ0320.csv','BZ0420.csv']
output_name = "test.xlsx"

from function1 import get, composite # need to import global value

getMerged(csv_files=csv_files, output_name=output_name)
print(composite)
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this as well.  Same result.  Im using Pycharm,  and when I start typing composite in other.py, it offers to autocomplete the typeout for me (indicating it found the global variable)... but running it executes nothing unfortunately. It does not print the data frame, nor does it write to excel